# Revert to natural sorted order if string length is equal

Tags: java, sorting, comparator, performance

I am trying to read a file, and compare string lengths. If two strings are of same length, then i would like to sort them in natural sorted order (alphabetical).

This is a snippet of the comparator I am working on. Everything is complete minus the sorting same length strings.

```
    Collections.sort(s, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return o1.length() - o2.length();
        }
    });
```

Thanks for any input or adivce

Comment: Side comment: you can also use `return Integer.compare(o1.length(), o2.length())`, which avoids the risk of integer overflow (it is unlikely to happen in your case but  it is a good practice anyway).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just put an if else block in your compare method.

Pseudocode:

```
if lengths are not equal 
   return o1's length compared to o2's length.
else 
   return o1 compared to o2.
```

I think that you can figure out the rest.

Answer (score 1):

So in terms of actual code, it'll be something like:

```
    Collections.sort(strList, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            int returnVal = 0;

            //handle nulls, there's some sample logic:
            if(o1 == null && o2 == null){
                returnVal = 0;
            } else
            if(o1 == null && o2 != null){
                returnVal = 1;
            } else
            if(o1 != null && o2 == null){
                returnVal = -1;
            } else {

                //sort by length
                returnVal = ((Integer)o1.length()).compareTo((Integer)o2.length());
                //if equal length, sort by string
                if(returnVal == 0){
                    returnVal = o1.compareTo(o2);
                }

            }
            return returnVal;
        }
    });
```

I've also added logic for null checks, and for moving them to the end of the sorted list. There may be different utils that already does this and you can just call it.

Also note, if you want the string compare to ignore case, use String.compareToIgnoreCase() method instead.